My device is unable to open an excel app with xlwings or win32com.client, but I need to refresh an excel file to pull data that is editted earlier
I have a pretty long program that basically edits the first sheet of an Excel file with some data, and then the second sheet of the Excel file does some math and fitting to the data and then the third sheet of the file pulls the relevant parameters to one row.
I have no issues with any of this, however when I try to pull the data fsom the third sheet with pandas.read_excel, the values that are pulled form the second sheet into the third sheet via some formulas in Excel are read as NaN. I am able to pull the values that I had just edited with no issues, it's just values that rely on formulas that are the issue, as I am putting these prameters into a dataframe to be inputted into a second Excel file.
I know there is a solution, because I got it working once before, but then my entire project got deleted, and I cannot for the life of me remember how I did it. Any help would be appreciated.
I've tried every variation of load_workbook() and save, xlwings app opening and saving and win32com app opening and waiting until all queries are done and then saving and exiting, however xlwings and win32com both give me this error:
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)
During the handling of the above exception another exception occurred
...
KeyError: 'My_File.xlsx'
During the handling of the above exception another exception occurred
com_error Traceback (most recent call last)
---> ex_book = ex_app.books.open(path)
...
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

I get a very similar error with win32com.client and pythoncom
import xlwings as xl
import win32com.client as win32

def refresh_data(path):

#One example of an attempt I made with xlwings 

wb = load_workbook(path)
ex_app = xl.App(visible=False)
ex_book = ex_app.books.open(path)
ex_book.save()
ex_book.close()
ex_app.quit()

Below is one version of the attemped wn32com.client usage
XLAPP = win32.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
book= XLAPP.Workbooks.Open(path)
book.RefreshAll()
XLAPP.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
book.save()
XLAPP.Quit()
'''


You need to use an absolute path, e.g. c:\tmp\data\
Try this:
import os
path = os.path.abspath(path)


Hi, unfortunately I am already using absolute paths.
